# Pass function argument (dict inside a tuple)

Tags: python, function, url

I am writing a function to generate an API url which accept multiple arguments and replicates a part of the string. The short version(which only accept one value for variable `Val`) looks like this

```
def get_url(par,att,value, _filter):

    base_url='''https://mytest.com/api/Test/'''+str(par)+'''?size=100000&filters=['''
    url = base_url + '''{"VarA" : "'''+att+'''", "Val":["'''+value+'''"], "VarB":"'''+_filter+'''"}]'''

    return url


print(get_url('Sales',{'Year':['2020'] , "Time"}))
```

This will return

```
https://mytest.com/api/Test/Sales?size=1000&filters=[{"VarA" : "Year", "Val":["2020"], "VarB":"Time"}]
```

I wrote another function so that I can pass multiple variable for `Val` while also replicating the filter string using the below function

```
def get_url(par,argv=None, _filter=None):
    if argv:
        att=argv
        url='''https://mytest.com/api/Test/'''+str(par)+'''?size=100000&filters=['''
        i=0
        for key in att.keys():
            attribute=key
            attribute_value=att[attribute]
            my_lst_str = '","'.join(map(str, attribute_value))
            values= '"'+my_lst_str+'"'
            if i==0:
                url=url+'''{"VarA" : "'''+attribute+'''", "Val":['''+value+'''], "VarB":'''+str(_filter)+'''}]'''
            else:url=url+''',{"VarA" : "'''+attribute+'''", "Val":['''+value+'''], "VarB":'''+str(_filter)+'''}]'''
            i+=1

    else:
        url = #Some string#

    return url


url = get_url('Sales',{'Loc':['USA','CAN'],'Year':["2016","2017"]},{'Country','Time'})
```

But what the above code returns is this

```
https://mytest.com/api/Test/Sales?size=1000&filters=[{"VarA" : "Loc", "Val":["USA","CAN"], "VarB":"{'Country', 'Time'}"}],{"VarA" : "Year", "Val":["2016","2017"], "VarB":"{'Country', 'Time'}"}]
```

My expected output is

```
https://mytest.com/api/Test/Sales?size=1000&filters=[{"VarA" : "Loc", "Val":["USA","CAN"], "VarB":"Country"},{"VarA" : "Year", "Val":["2020","2017"], "VarB":"Time"}]
```

How do I isolate element for `VarB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your index:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def get_url(par, argv=None, _filter=None):
    obj_list, obj_filter = [], list(_filter)
    if argv:
        att = argv
        url = (
            """https://mytest.com/api/Test/""" + str(par) + """?size=100000&filters="""
        )
        i = 0
        for key in att.keys():
            attribute = key
            attribute_value = att[attribute]
            obj_list.append({"VarA" : attribute, "Val": attribute_value, "VarB": obj_filter[i]})
            i += 1

    else:
        url = "some url"

    return url+str(obj_list)


url = get_url(
    "Sales", OrderedDict({"Loc": ["USA", "CAN"], "Year": ["2016", "2017"], "wewe": ["4", "5"]}), {"Country", "Time", "wre"}
)
print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://mytest.com/api/Test/Sales?size=100000&filters=[{'VarA': 'Loc', 'Val': ['USA', 'CAN'], 'VarB': 'wre'}, {'VarA': 'Year', 'Val': ['2016', '2017'], 'VarB': 'Time'}, {'VarA': 'wewe', 'Val': ['4', '5'], 'VarB': 'Country'}]
```

Comment: But what if there are more than 2 values available for `VarB`, won't make sense to hard code index in code

Comment: @TNT see my edit, I think this is the approach you should have.

Comment: Like I said in my earlier comment, the above is just an example I don't know beforehand what value `VarA` and `VarB` are going to hold. Hardcoding is not an option for me here.

Comment: @TNT See my edit, maybe use your index.

Comment: @TNT see my last edit seems more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention: **The order of elements in a set is undefined though it may consist of various elements.** By converting a `set` to a `list` you cannot be sure that the order would remain the same!

```py
>>> li = list({"Country", "Time", "w", "z"})
>>> li
['z', 'Country', 'w', 'Time']
```

The code in the question does not run as well.

My answer is based on your expected output, and I did not consider edge cases, I highly suggest to change the function arguments. Also, I considered `_filter` a list, `["Country", "Time"]`.

```py
def get_url(par, att=None, _filter=None):
    url = f"https://mytest.com/api/Test/{par}?size=100000&filters="
    if att:
        result_list = [{'VarA':k, 'Val':v} for k , v in att.items()]
    else: return "some string"  

    if _filter:
        _filter.reverse()
        for d in result_list:
            d["VarB"] = _filter.pop()
    return f"{url}{result_list}"

url = get_url(
    "Sales", {"Loc": ["USA", "CAN"], "Year": ["2016", "2017"], "wewe": ["4", "5"]}, ["Country", "Time", "wre"]
)
print(url)

# https://mytest.com/api/Test/Sales?size=100000&filters=[{'VarA': 'Loc', 'Val': ['USA', 'CAN'], 'VarB': 'Country'}, {'VarA': 'Year', 'Val': ['2016', '2017'], 'VarB': 'Time'}, {'VarA': 'wewe', 'Val': ['4', '5'], 'VarB': 'wre'}]
```